# Vertically center carousel items in responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive, bootstrap-carousel

I have a carousel with items that have variable height in **responsive**, and I want to center them vertically in the .carousel-inner container. And I do (using flex, top & transform, etc)... but they're centered only when they have finished the animation when becoming active, so they are aligned top at first, then go down and it seems like it jumps.

I think it's something about the Bootstrap animations for the carousel but I haven't figure it out. The page is https://zuckermanlaw.swapps.io, the carousel is in the Our Services section. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the height same as your carousel-inner class has to below mention class, though it stretch images a little bit but fix your issue.

```
section.third-section #carousel-our-services .carousel-inner .item .carousel-caption {
        display: flex;
        height: 365px;    
    }
```

I hope this helps you.
Enjoy :)

Comment: That's the height for desktop, but still worked great for responsive equaling the heights. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I played around with this and came up with this.

```
    @media (-webkit-transform-3d), not all
    .carousel-inner>.item.active, .carousel-inner>.item.next.left, .carousel-inner>.item.prev.right {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(0,-50%); // IE9
transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0); // Modern Browsers 
    }
```

I replaced all declarations for that selector. It changes the animation style, but it does vertically align. Personally, I think that looks cool but you might not. I thought it was still worth showing to you. It might be a good start for you. I did this in the browser inspector, and that was the only change I made.

Comment: Though it should be noted that this is really heavy and might make the images lose quality. -- on the other hand, this is most definitely the most effective and easy fix I know of.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, BabyD!

Comment: I liked it, but that animation can't be accepted at work. Anyways, thanks for helping!